# refreshLocal on IResource throws exception

Tags: eclipse, concurrency, eclipse-plugin, synchronization, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to programmatically refresh a folder inside the project for my Eclipse plugin. I have also included a simple semaphore rule in the Job. Here is the code:

```
public class MutexRule implements ISchedulingRule {
    public boolean isConflicting(ISchedulingRule rule) {
        return rule == this;
    }
    public boolean contains(ISchedulingRule rule) {
        return rule == this;
    }
}
...

Job refreshJob = new Job("Refreshing...") {

    public void run() {
        IResource myFolder = ...
        if(myFolder != null)
            myFolder.refreshLocal(DEPTH_INFINITE, null);
    }
};
refreshJob.setRule(
```

When I schedule two jobs, and run the refresh, I get the following exception:

```
Attempted to beginRule: P/test, does not match outer scope rule: ...
```

What am I missing?
What is a possible solution / workaround?

Comment: You don't need to do any of this. IResources already schedule themselves. In fact, they implement ISchedulingRule.

Comment: @nitind Do you then propose that refreshes do not need to be in jobs?

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting is because the `IResource` you are refreshing also has a scheduling rule (`IResource` implements `ISchedulingRule`). When there are nested scheduling rules the outer rule must 'contain' the inner rule - your `MutexRule` doesn't do this.

Because the resource already has a scheduling rule there is no need to set a rule on your job.

`refreshLocal` does not have to in a `Job` but if it is run from the UI thread a progress monitor should be provided using `IProgressService` or similar.

Update: `refreshLocal` can generate many resource changed events, to minimize these use a `WorkspaceModifyOperation` or a `WorkspaceJob`:

```java
Job job = new WorkspaceJob("Refreshing") {

   public IStatus runInWorkspace(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
      monitor.beginTask("", IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN);          

      try {
        resource.refreshLocal(monitor);
      }
      finally {
        monitor.done();
      }

      return Status.OK_STATUS;
   }
});
```

or

```java
WorkspaceModifyOperation op = new WorkspaceModifyOperation() {

    @Override
    protected void execute(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {

      resource.refreshLocal(monitor);

    }
};
```

If you are in a wizard page you can run the `WorkspaceModifyOperation` with:

```java
getContainer().run(true, true, op);
```

elsewhere you can use:

```java
IProgressService service = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getProgressService();

service.run(true, true, op);
```

Even better is to use the Eclipse `IFile` and `IFolder` APIs to create files and folders, in this case `refreshLocal` is not required.

Comment: @greg449 Thanks for your response! Could you please share some code?